# Why does my WIX installer not copy the richtx32.ocx to system32 dir?

Tags: security, installation, wix, privileges, system32

My WIX (3.5) installer should copy the richtx32.ocx file to the windows\system32 dir and register it by using some command line statements but it does not work.
The file is not copied to the folder.

```
<Directory Id="SystemFolder">
   <Component Id="ComponentName" Guid="someGUID">
      <File Source="someSourceFolder\richtx32.ocx" />
   </Component>
</Directory>
```

The problem occurs on XP and also on 7 and yes, I have started the MSI as admin user. In case the file is copied to another directory (eg. the program files directory of my application), everything works fine.

The error occurs only with the system32 dir. I also tried it with another .ocx file to see wether the problems lies within the file itself, but it seems as if I cannot copy any file to the folder.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

If I add a "test.txt" file to the component (which btw. has some more files then only the richtx32.ocx) it suddenly works! But why does the installer only copy all files if there is a different file like .ocx or .dll?? I don't want to copy a dummy text file just to let it work... There must be a reason.

Comment: Try creating an installation log to determine why the file is not copied: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm

Comment: I already did but the install log does not help me. Instead of a FileCopy there is only this entry: Executing op: CacheRTMFile(,FileKey=richtx32.ocx,,ProductCode={3591F66A-3E04-4E50-9251-9A588D31ED77},ProductVersion=1.0.0,Attributes=512,,,,CopierFlags=2,FileSize=203976,,,,,)

Comment: Can you copy the file manually? Also, is your package configured to install per-machine (ALLUSERS = "1")?

Comment: Yes, its configured as per machine and I can copy it manually.

Comment: Can you post a link to the full log so we can take a look?

Comment: Sorry but due to company restrictions it's not possible. Maybe you have an idea what I should look for? Some keywords?

Comment: In my case there was something about how '20 characters will be replaced' in System32 to Sys64Wow.  It was rewriting the file path from System32 to the 64 bit version